# Basic questions about DMG and copying Mac OS Install CD as a backup

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, leopard, dmg

I have a Mac OS X Install DVD (Leopard 10.5.6).

How do I store a copy of this Leopard Install DVD to my PC Laptop?

I want to have it as a backup. My MacBook won't boot so I will need to reinstall the OS. But before I do that I want a backup of the OS Install DVD in case the DVD won't eject from the MacBook.

The info on Google is about making "bootable USB sticks", but I just want to store a copy of the Mac operating system on my PC laptop.

Here are my questions.

1) I cannot simply copy the files of the Install DVD and paste it onto my PC Laptop. Is this correct?

2) I need to get a DMG image file of the Install DVD. Is this correct?

3) Is the Install DVD already a DMG file? Or do I need to create a DMG file?

4) On my Windows laptop, I put the Leopard Install DVD inside, but none of the folders contain a DMG or ISO file. Is it hidden? Is it because I am on a Windows laptop?

Screenshots of the files inside of my 10.5.6 OS Install DVD being viewed on a Windows laptop:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not trying to install Mac OS on my PC. I want to store a copy on my Mac OS Install CD on my PC (as a back up). Sorry but is there a more appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: It's a DVD not a CD. If you want to store a digital copy of the Mac OS X Install DVD then on a Mac, make a "DVD/CD master" image of it using Disk Utility. Then you can store the image wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it's a DVD. Not too familiar with the terms. My macbook won't boot so I cannot use Disk Utility. -- I am starting to comprehend everything except for one thing. -- I read that Moiuntain Lion Install DVD already contains a DMG. Does this mean for Mountain Lion Install DVD I would NOT need a cloning software or Disk Utility? I would simply drag the DMG file onto my PC desktop (so I can store as a backup)?

Comment: OS X Mountain Lion never shipped as a DVD. There is absolutely no reason you need to make a copy of the DVD before you install Mac OS X!  Just boot your Mac from the DVD and install Mac OS X.

Comment: My logic is this...I need a copy of the DVD because I'm afraid to lose my Leopard Install DVD because it's so old that Apple doesn't sell it. -- My macbook won't boot and I need to get my data. Before I boot from the DVD, as a precaution, I wanted to get a copy of the DVD. John's comment is reassuring but I'm just preparing for the worst. And I don't have Mountain Lion, I was just asking to fully understand this topic/DMG.

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the CD out. If the drive works, hold the mouse or trackpad button and power on the Mac. If the drive doesn't work, it won't accept a disc as the arms gripping the disk won't unlock and retract. In case they already are retracted, the CD will go in but will not be gripped, so it will come out by holding the Mac on it's side and letting gravity do it's work.

With regards to the backup issue: it's a hybrid DVD, probably dual-layer. To read it, you need disk cloning software for optical media with raw read capability. You then can burn it back to a DVD whenever you like.

Comment: That's good to know about the stuck CD. Phew. Also, must the software indicate that the file is "bootable"? I put the Install DVD and the software says it is an ISO but it doesn't mention "bootable". Does this mean that it won't be bootable when I use it as an Install DVD?

Comment: No, when using proper CD/DVD software that can read and reconstruct hybrid DVD's, all that data is kept as well, so no problems there. Additionally: if your Mac is really old (like, 10.5 Leopard old), it probably also supports the safety pin eject method. If it doesn't, it might be new enough to support Internet Recovery.

Comment: Oh okay. But one question. Why does Mountain Lion have a DMG file in the Install DVD but not Leopard? For Moiuntain Lion, I would not need a cloning software? I just drag the DMG file onto my PC desktop (so I can store as a backup)?

Comment: Because it's different software, packaged in a different way. It started that way with Lion.

Comment: Ohh I see. Did you see my second question I edited it in?: For Moiuntain Lion, I would not need a cloning software? I would just drag the DMG file onto my PC desktop (so I can store as a backup)? I don't have Mountain Lion, I was just asking so I can fully understand this topic

Comment: Well, you can store ISO's, DMG's and raw images on your PC, but the real issue is making a proper bootable CD/DVD or USB drive for the Mac. With optical media, you have the benefit of a standard raw master image being burnable, but for USB drives, you'll need to have a working USB drive, and then make a raw image off of that and store it on a PC. In theory, you should be able to use the PC to do the correct GPT formatting and moving data on to the correct partitions, but with it's lack of HFS+ support, a raw USB drive image is a safer choice. Going to an Apple Store with a USB drive is easier.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this article? http://www.sysprobs.com/create-iso-mac-installation-dvd-rip-mac-dvd-windows

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have read many tutorials but I am asking these newbie questions to ensure that I am comprehending everything. I am still not fully clear on especially my Question 3 and 4. Also, why does your link say to use ISO? and not DMG?

Comment: PCs cannot directly write DMGs. They can only read over 3rd Party software. An ISO is a byte for byte copy of the contents of the disk. (When copied correctly)

Comment: Do you know... Is the Install DVD already a DMG file? Or do I need to create a DMG file?

Comment: The Install DVD is NOT A DMG and a DMG doesn't need to be created.

Comment: A DMG is basically an ISO for Mac.

Comment: In order to store a copy of the Install DVD, I would need a ISO of the files on the Install DVD? (In other words I need an ISO and I cannot simply copy the files and paste on my PC desktop) - Is this correct logic?

Comment: Yes. You can use different softwares, including (but not limited to) Roxio's Toast, http://infrarecorder.org/, and a few others. Just insert the disk, open the program, and click Copy Disk.